# How to capture the active section or tab of the swipeable tabs in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using swipeable tabs as part of an activity with a total of 3 sections. I'm providing the right and left arrows to navigate to the other sections of the swipe-view.

I want my left arrow to disappear when I'm at the leftmost section and my right-arrow to disappear when I'm at the rightmost section.

Here's what I'm trying rightnow, but not getting the desired result:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    static Button rightButton;
    static Button leftButton;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rightButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
        leftButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


         // Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            int sectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            String text = instructions(sectionNumber);
            textView.setText(text);
            return rootView;
        }

        private String instructions(int sectionNumber) {
            if (sectionNumber == 1) {
                leftButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                rightButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.i("Welcome"," to section 1");
                return "All questions are mandatory. Each question carries 1 mark. There is no negative marking";
            }
            else if(sectionNumber == 2) {
                leftButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rightButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.i("Welcome", " to section 2");
                return "Color the bubble besides the option you think is best for the answer.";
            }
            else {
                leftButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rightButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.i("Welcome", " to section 3");
                return "Click on the skip button above to start the test. Timer will start as soon as you'll click that button!";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the method `instructions`, I tried using logs to see what's happening only to find that I never get the "Welcome to section 2" part even after swiping through the tabs multiple times. Although, the texts related to a given section are returned correctly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you returned a new fragment in getItem

Do it like this:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragments.add(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1));
        mFragments.add(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(2));
        mFragments.add(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(3));
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     return mFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

Also change the Buttons to the fragment_main layout "not" in activity_main and use it like this.

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

     private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
     private  Button rightButton;
     private  Button leftButton;

     // Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.

     public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
         PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
         Bundle args = new Bundle();
         args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
         fragment.setArguments(args);
         return fragment;
     }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        rightButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
        leftButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
        int sectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        String text = instructions(sectionNumber);
        textView.setText(text);
        return rootView;
    }
```

EDIT if you want to know the cuurent page you have to implement this.

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.i("Welcome", "page "+ position+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Also add the following line so that the system will create your fragment only once:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

The issue you had is that you're getting the position that the system created now not the current page.

Comment: Well I tried like you suggested, but unfortunately, it didn't work out. Same problem.

Comment: Same issue. I'm on the first section. I swipe right once to reach section 2. The log shows me "welcome to section 3".  I swipe right again and reach the 3rd section. No logs shown. I swipe left to get back to section 2. Log shows "welcome to section 1". I swipe left again to go to section 1. Log shows nothing.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is quite helpful and i'm able to achieve the results by little more edits.